# Google's user token and authorization code in an ASP.NET webapplication

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-api, xmlhttprequest, google-api-dotnet-client

Hello I'm trying to make a web application that can read the users email even when they are not connected to the web site . I followed the steps right here in the   [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret) and made a javascript Sign-in page that ends up giving me an authorization code , in step 7 they tell you to exchange the authorization code for an access token by sending it to the server through  xmlhttprequest . My problems are  I don't know how to send the code to the server side , and even if I did I have no idea how to use it to refresh the token or get users data in asp , I searched how to use DotNetOpenAuth but I couldn't find a tutorial to help me on my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can do something like that:

```
IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = 
new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(newGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "yourClientId",
    ClientSecret = "yourClientSecret"

});
TokenResponse response = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("", "authorization_code_you_generated_in_client", "postmessage", CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

This should give you the access token.
You will get the refresh token only if you specified the `"access_type" : "offline"` in javascript request.
You may also want to use `"approval_prompt" : "force"` to get the refresh_token again.

Comment: Thank you , I used GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker after all but i'm having difficulties getting offline access with it, do ou happen to have any idea  ?

Comment: From my experience, the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker is better for desktop apps, in your scenario i would use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow. Did you specify access_type and approval_prompt in client side as I mentioned to get the refresh_token?